# d3 chart not showing inside a div but shows when it's on body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

When I am showing the d3 chart on the body it works fine but when I want to show it inside a div it doesn't show up. Any help would be appreciated.

This works

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
```

This doesn't work

```
var svg = d3.select("#issues").append("svg")
```

where `issues` is an id of a div

Comment: That **does** work. You'll have to provide more information.

Comment: Please create a fiddle for solving it faster.

Comment: too vague. show more context